# Parse nested arguments using argparser python

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I need to have an argument parsing logic that is able to parse below examples:

```
python3 some_script.py --build_config target=product1 step=x rom=y flavors=A B C
python3 some_script.py --build_config target=product1 flavors=A --build_config target=product2 flavors=B C
```

I tried using argparse but I am quite not able to get it working.

Comment: I can only guess what you are trying to, but it looks a lot more complicated than what `argparse` can handle.  `argparse` handles 3 things `optionals`, `positionals`, and `subparsers` (a sub type of positional.  Don't try be too complicated.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Are you aware how I could achieve this if not via `argparse`.

Comment: i don't want to guess

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see how the shell splits the inputs into a list of strings.  That's what the parse has to work with.  '--buildconig' is only thing that looks like `optional's` flag.  The rest are just strings, arguments.  `argparse` does nothing with 'key=value' strings.  There are lots of questions trying accept those, all with kludgy answers.  Practice more with straight forward usages before trying something unusual.